# guzzle returns error 6: could not resolve hot api

Tags: php, phpunit, guzzle

I just finished installing guzzle for first time and tried to run first test. I copied a simple example from the web and tried to run it, but for some reason i get the following error:

```
GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException: cURL error 6: Could not resolve host: api (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)
```

I checked the address in my browser and the  request returned this json :

```
{"status":{"Production":"green","Development":"green"},"issues":[]}
```

the code looks like this:

```
require dirname(__FILE__).'/../../src/vendor/autoload.php';

use GuzzleHttp\Client;

class ApiTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
        /**
    * Tests heroku status is green
    */
    public function testHerokuStatus()
    {
        $client = new Client(['base_url' => 'https://status.heroku.com']); 
        $request = $client->get('api/v3/current-status');
        $response = $request;                                          
        $decodedResponse = $response->json();
        $this->assertEquals($decodedResponse['status']['Production'], 'green');
        $this->assertEquals($decodedResponse['status']['Development'], 'green');
    }
}
```

why does guzzle generates this error?
thx

**UPDATE:**
when i tried adding `/` in the beginning of the `$client->get` i got this error:

`1) ApiTest::testHerokuStatus
GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException: cURL error 3: <url> malformed (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)`

if it helps in any way

Comment: Have you tried with a slash before the api as follow: `$request = $client->get('/api/v3/current-status');` ?

Comment: yes...please see update

Comment: I tried your code e works fine...

Comment: so i guess the question is what is wrong/bad configed in my machine...

Comment: i tested it with Guzzle 4.2.3 (2014-10-05)

Comment: simply try to execute the *curl* via command line as follow: `curl https://status.heroku.com/api/v3/current-status`